# How to run while loop here?

Tags: c++

Okay so here is my code, everything is working fine except the while loop.
The purpose of this program is to input a number "40235" and then dividing it by 10, taking it's remainder (5), subtracting it from main number, and then dividing it by 10, to get it it's perfect quotient i.e 4023. I did managed to run the code, but while loop is not iterating. (Yes, I do know I have to take the sum of remainders, but first I need to figure out how to iterate the while loop).
This loop has to iterate until 40235 becomes zero.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Program to yield exact quotient and sum of remainders: "<<endl;
    int num, remainder_1, a, subtract;
    cout<<"Enter a number: "<<endl
    cin>>num;


    while(num!=0)
    {
        remainder_1 =num%10;
        num=num-remainder_1;
        a =num/10;
        cout<<a<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When a program does something I don't expect, my first thought is to output all the values and see if they are all what I am expecting them to be.  For example, in your case, I might do `cout << "Num:" << num << " Remainder:" << remainder_1 << " A:" << a << " subtract:" << subtract << endl;` instead of a single `cout << a << endl;`.

Comment: Would you expect `num==0` to be "true" or "false" when you enter 40235 for your `num`?

Comment: I think you want `num=num/10`, not `a=num/10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code:

1. Your loop condition is opposite, it should be `while( num != 0 )`
2. You do not need to subtract reminder from num, integer division will take care of that
3. You do not assign `num/10` back to `num` so if your condition would be right your loop will never end.

It should be something like:

```
while( num!=0 )
{
    remainder_1 = num%10;
    // do something with reminder
    num /= 10; // short form of num = num / 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   //...

    while(num != 0)
    {
   //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured it out. Thanks alot, everyone!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Program to yield exact quotient and sum of remainders: "<<endl;
    int num, remainder_1, a, subtract;
    cout<<"Enter a number: "<<endl;
    cin>>num;
    int sum;

    while(num!=0)
    {
        remainder_1 =num%10;
        num/=10;
        cout<<num<<endl;
        sum+=remainder_1;

    }
    cout<<"The Sum is: \t"<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```